# Default Route does not work after upgrading to MVC5 with Attribute Routing

Tags: attributerouting, asp.net-mvc-5.2

After upgrading from MVC4 with AttributeRouting.net to MVC5 with MVC5's attribute routing, I can't seem to get the default route working so that `http://server` defaults to `http://server/home/index` . Browsing directly to `/home/` or `/home/index` works fine.

For route config, I have this:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The HomeController declaration looks like this:

```
// Controller
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : MvcControllerBase
....
    // Action
    [HttpGet, Route, Route("index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
   .....
```

I'm not sure where else to check.  I've commented out everything in Global and disabled all WebActivator-activated items.

And ideas? The response is 404 with no exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.. got it!

Based on Kiran's answer to : [Specify default controller/action route in WebAPI using AttributeRouting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265653/specify-default-controller-action-route-in-webapi-using-attributerouting)

I changed HomeController to:

```
// Controller
public class HomeController : MvcControllerBase
....
    // Action
    [HttpGet, Route, Route("home"), Route("home/index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
....
```

And I got rid of the MVC Config default.